# Where am I wrong? The code never catch an exception while trying to createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Please direct how to catch firebase auth Exception.  I have  used already added emails to sign up, console shows error messages but I could not catch the error by try-catch method.

```
Future signUp() async {
        final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
        if (!isValid) return;
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 2,`enter code here`
                ));
        try {
          FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text.trim(),
            password: confirmPasswordController.text.trim(),
          );
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Error'),
                content: Text('${e.message}'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: const Text('Ok'))
                ],
              );
            },
          );
```

Comment: your code seems correct , did you make sure to use print() instead of dialog ? and see if it prints errors ?

Comment: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is async, try to call it like `await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword...`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your solution but still not resolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed  --- formkey.currentstate.validate().
Now its working

thank you....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about how to catch errors from firebase
[ُError Handling](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).